# Converting dates of format "2012 Week15" in r

Tags: r

I've got a data frame with a date column of the format specified in the title, I would like to know of a simple way to convert them to the standard date format i.e "yyyy-mm-dd" or similar.

So currently my date column is in the format

```
2012 Week15
2012 Week12
2012 Week16
2012 Week25
2012 Week4
```

So far I have tried:

```
df$Date<-gsub("Week","",df$Date)
con.date<-as.Date(df$Date, format="%Y %V")
df<-data.frame(date=con.date,df[,columns excluding the date column])
```

and

```
df$Date<-as.Date( df$Date,"%Y %V" )
```

but these just produce the same date for each year  i.e

```
2012-07-31  
2012-07-31  
2012-07-31
```

for some reason.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the desired output for "2012 Week15" ?

Comment: 2012-4-19 i.e the 15th week of 2012

Comment: Hi David I've added some sample output from the date column sorry for the confusion about weeks and dates.

Comment: ?strptime says the week starts on Monday but that %V is "Accepted but ignored on input". Your examples are ignoring the week and just giving you the middle day of the year.

Comment: Do you want your week definition to start on Monday, Saturday, Sunday? Can you have a short Week 1 if the year starts on a Thursday? Or does the week start on Jan 1 every year? It may just be a question of adding `7*week` to Jan 1st for any given year.

Comment: Hi Spacedman, so I need to supply a day of the week for the %V operator to work? I must have glistened over that in the docs - I'll take another look.

Comment: That's what I have done in the past when I had a separate "week" column but it seems like too long a process when there is a "%V" option in the standard docs.

Comment: `%V` is for converting dates to weeks, not the opposite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment i wrote a function which only convert a vector with length 1 to your desired output. where i count 01-01 to 01-07 as week 1 etc. And for week 1 i will output the first date of the week.

```
WeekToDate <- function(Date) {
    install.packages("Hmisc")
    library(Hmisc)
    year <- substr(Date, 1,4)
    week <- substring(Date, 10)
    date1 <- as.Date(paste(year, "-01-01", sep=""), format="%Y-%m-%d")
    Date.list <- seq(date1, date1+yearDays(date1), by="day")
    data <- data.frame(Date.list)
    data$Week <- as.numeric(format(data$Date.list, "%U"))
    data <- data[!duplicated(data$Week),]
    output <- data[data$Week==week,]$Date.list
    return(output)
}
```

output would be

```
 > WeekToDate("2013 Week15")
Installing package into ‘D:/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: package ‘Hmisc’ is in use and will not be installed
[1] "2013-04-14"
```